# Prove inequality with the largest power $v_{p}(n!)>\frac{n-1}{p-1}-\frac{\ln{n}}{\ln{p}}$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p$ be prime number,show that
>   $$v_{p}(n!)>\dfrac{n-1}{p-1}-\dfrac{\ln{n}}{\ln{p}}\tag{1}$$
>   where where $v_{p}{(n)}$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing $n$.

I use this [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) :
$$v_{p}(n!)=\dfrac{n-S_{p}(n)}{p-1}$$
where $S_{p}(n)$ denotes the sum of the standard base$-p$ digits of $n$,
and we know $S_{p}(n)<[\log_{p}{(n)}]$, so we have :
$$v_{p}(n!)=\dfrac{n-S_{p}(n)}{p-1}>\dfrac{n-[\log_{p}{n}]}{p-1}$$
But use this I can't prove inequality $(1)$, so how to prove $(1)$ ?

Comment: Isn't it $S_p(n)\leq(p-1)\lfloor\log_p(n)\rfloor$?

Answer (score 2):

If we consider the standard base$-p$ of $n$, each of its digits is in $\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$ and its number of digits is $\lfloor\log_{p}{n}\rfloor$, so $S_p(n)\leq(p-1)\lfloor\log_p(n)\rfloor$. Thus we get :
$$v_{p}(n!)=\dfrac{n-S_{p}(n)}{p-1}\geq\dfrac{n-(p-1)\lfloor\log_p(n)\rfloor}{p-1}>\dfrac{n-1-(p-1)\lfloor\log_p(n)\rfloor}{p-1}\\=\frac{n-1}{p-1}-\lfloor\log_p(n)\rfloor=\frac{n-1}{p-1}-\left\lfloor\frac{\log(n)}{\log(p)}\right\rfloor\geq\frac{n-1}{p-1}-\frac{\log(n)}{\log(p)}$$
We obtained the inequality wanted :
$$v_{p}(n!)>\dfrac{n-1}{p-1}-\dfrac{\ln{n}}{\ln{p}}$$